# How to stop JWPlayer from turning black at the end of the video

Tags: html, video, screen, jwplayer

Every time JWPlayer finished playing a video it fades to black. I'd rather it just showed the last frame of the video. Is there any way to do that?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function changeVideo(filename) {
 jwplayer("video").remove();
 jwplayer("video").setup({
   file: filename,
   image: "img.jpg",
    height: 640,
    width: 480,
    controlbar: 'none',
    icons: 'false'
});
jwplayer('video').load();
jwplayer('video').play();
}
 </script>
```

```
</head>
<div id="video"></div>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("video").setup({
        file: "vid.mp4",
        image: "img.jpg",
        height: 640,
        width: 480,
        controlbar: 'none',
        icons: 'false'
    });
</script>
```

```
<p><a href="javascript:void();" onclick="javascript:changeVideo('vid2.mp4');">Vid2</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't show the last frame of the video, but you can just supply a poster image, which it will show before playing and after playing. Better than a blank screen.

Comment: Yes I did that but it still shows the black screen at the end of the video. Doesn't really solve anything.

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. Try my demo page - let the video finish (or drag the controls to about the 20 second mark). http://misterneutron.com/JW6video/

Answer (score 0):

You can use our JavaScript API to stop a second before the end of the video.

I actually wrote a small plugin for this.

Demo - http://www.pluginsbyethan.com/github/stopatend.html

Plugin - https://github.com/emaxsaun/stopatend

Hope this helps you!

Edit:

For your changeVideo function, use this instead:

```
function changeVideo(filename) {
 jwplayer("video").setup({
   file: filename,
   image: "img.jpg",
    height: 640,
    width: 480,
    controlbar: 'none',
    icons: 'false',
    autostart: true
});
}
```

By calling setup you are basically removing already, and you can't just do a load() by itself, and doing load() is the same as autostart = true, try that.

Comment: Wow it works great. Only one issue I have is that I have other videos where when I click them they change the main video. The initial loaded video stops just before the end as desired but when I click a link to load another video, that one will not stop at the end. Any ideas?

Comment: My script only works for the first player instance on the page. You should try to make it so that subsequent videos remove() and then setup() the player, so the same player instance is used again, then.

Comment: That doesn't work. I want you to look at my code but I don't seem to be able to edit this question now.

Comment: Hm, can you provide a link?

Comment: Unfortunately its not online yet.

Comment: Ok I can edit it, I don't know what I was thinking. Ok I've added the code in now.

Comment: Sorry, I want to see the implementation in action to debug properly. However, you can simplify your code a bit. See my updated answer.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle but it doesn't work quite the same:

http://jsfiddle.net/hasen/xxzmma5L/3/

The change video onclick doesn't work but I don't know why. I also don't know how to add stopatend.js to it.

Comment: Or, why don't you autostart your videos, and set a poster image for each video?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full HTML page of how to do this.

I could not add the full stop at end script here because it was too long for the answer, but I've tested this and it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Change Video</title>
    <script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/12/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    jwplayer("player").setup({
        file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/w5co0c24-hV866gPy.mp4",
        image: "img.jpg",
        height: 640,
        width: 480,
        controlbar: 'none',
        icons: 'false'
    });
    //PUT ENTIRE STOP AT END SCRIPT HERE
     function changeVideo(filename) {
     jwplayer("player").setup({
       file: filename,
       image: "img.jpg",
        height: 640,
        width: 480,
        controlbar: 'none',
        icons: 'false',
        autostart: true
    });
    //PUT ENTIRE STOP AT END SCRIPT HERE
    }
    </script>
    <p><a href="#" onclick='changeVideo("http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4");'>Vid2</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Paste the entire stop at end script in there twice? I considered that too actually but its so long it would make for some very untidy code. Especially if you needed loads of videos. Is there really no better way? Seems such a simple thing to just stop the video on the last frame but somehow it isn't.

Comment: Well, it works. It seems like loading the player again kills the events, which is why the script needs to be there again. I tested this, it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way to show the image at the end of the video. Just include this code:

```
playerInstance.onComplete(function() {
  playerInstance.stop();
});
```

This works in jwplayer version 7. If you use version 6 you want to upgrade to 7 to get rid of the logo. You need a key for 7, but it is free for personal use.

I use this function with multiple videos in a custom playlist. The entire Javascript code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
  file: "fileA.mp4",
  image: "fileA.jpg",
  width: 996,
  height: 560,
  captions: {
  fontSize: 12,
  backgroundOpacity: 50
  },
  tracks: [{
    file: "fileA.srt",
    "default": true
  }]
});
playerInstance.onComplete(function() {
  playerInstance.stop();
});

function playVideo(video,img,cc) {
  playerInstance.load([{
    file: video,
    image: img,
    tracks: [{
      file: cc,
      "default": true
    }]
  }]);
  playerInstance.play();
};
</script>
```

A click in your custom playlist should result in a call to playVideo. If you don't use captions you can omit cc and the captions and tracks blocks. Every video will show its corresponding image when playing is complete.